# Typescript allows redundant keys when resolving promise with object

Tags: typescript, object, promise, key

Could you please help me to understand why Typescript does not throw an error here:

```js
type Test = Promise<{a: number}>;
const test: Test = Promise.resolve({a: 1, something: 'wrong'}); // no error
```

but does here

```
type Test2 = {a: number};
const test2: Test2 = {a: 1, something: 'wrong'}; // error 2322, ok
```

And is there something I can do to make it throw the similar error with Promise?

Tried it on different versions on Typescript, including the latest one, with strict types.
Tried with `new Promise` instead of `Promise.resolve`. Nothing helps.
Take a look on [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=2&jsx=0&module=1&ts=4.1.5#code/FAFwngDgpgBAKlAziGBeGAFATgewLYCWiUAPAN4CGAXDAHYCueARlFgL4B8A3MAMY61kMEEhA0EQ9NnxEoAOixIcAGwBuUABSUaARgA0MRPiggAFgVoBzGgHIA7ris22ASi4wA9B5h3TYGAQoFMrKOHaIMIoAJvS0WBS0KADWUGARpqxQAPzAoJCwEiAATGgw2nSMLOw8-IIoIshF4qIl6OX6hsZmFtYw9o6WzjzAQA)

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TypeScript only does excess property checks in very limited situations (direct assignment of object literals to typed variables, returning an object literal from a function; [details here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#excess-property-checks)), because although from a type system perspective those extra properties are fine (they just mean the instance is of a subtype of the type which has more information), having them on an object literal you're assigning is typically a programmer mistake. It doesn't do that check otherwise because in the general case, it may well not be an error (just, again, a subtype).

You can trigger excess property checks on `Promise.resolve` by providing a type argument to it ([playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=72#code/MYewdgzgLgBFCm0YF4YAUBOIC2BLC8AdBoiADYBu8APAN4CGAXDGAK7YBG8GAvgHwAKBswCMAGhgQc8KAAtcYAObMA5AHcsSlTwCUAbhhA)) *(thanks [jcalz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2887218/jcalz)!)*:

```typescript
const test = Promise.resolve<{a: number}>({a: 1, something: 'wrong'});
//                                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^−− Argument of type '{ a: number; something: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ a: number; } | PromiseLike<{ a: number; }>'
```

In that, TypeScript will infer `test`'s type as `Promise<{a: number}>` (e.g., your `Test` type).

You also get the check on `async` function returns ([playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKhDOwoF4oAUBOB7AtgS3ggB4BvAQwC4oA7AVxwCMIMBfAPgG4AoM+EagMZQAZrUHA8WalF78BAUQAeZHGAA2EABSUa9JhgCUVOIigkuUS1AwRgtDNPIAaKBEXAMOj7QgtuLIA)):

```typescript
type Test = Promise<{a: number}>;
async function asyncExample(a: number): Test {
    return {a, extra: true}; // Type '{ a: number; extra: boolean; }' is not assignable to type '{ a: number; }'
}
```

...so if you can use an `async` function rather than explicit promise syntax, you might be able to tighten up the checks.

Comment: You can also do `Promise.resolve<{ a: number }>({ a: 1, something: 'wrong' });` if you want to see an error, and it might be helpful to provide the handbook link to [excess property checks](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#excess-property-checks).

Comment: @jcalz - Oh, I didn't think you were. :-) I'll do that. I really appreciate your pointing stuff this out to me, BTW.